# Creating a Stack containing a class

Tags: c++, oop, constructor, stack

I have this Album class that I want to use as a Stack for a Song class.This is what I did so far:

---

```
const int intial_capacity=2; 
class Album
{
  Song* songs;
  char* name;
  int top;
  int capacity;
public:
 ...
};
bool Album::empty() const {
return top == -1;
}
bool Album::full() const {
return top == capacity - 1;
}
Song Album::pop() {
if (empty())
    return ???
return songs[top--];
}
Song Album::last() const {
if (empty())
    return ???
return songs[top];
}
bool ResizingStack::push(Song x) {
if (full())
resize();
songs[++top] = x;
return true;
}
void Album::resize() {
capacity *= 2;
int* newsongs = new Song[capacity];
for(int i = 0; i < capacity / 2; i++)
newsongs[i] = songs[i];
delete[] songs;
songs = newsongs;
}
```

---

I don't exactly know how to make my constructors and destructors so they can allocate memory correctly and don't give me crashes, also what should I return if Album is empty, it contains a compound type so I can't simply return 0 or '\0'. Any help is welcomed :)

Comment: If someone asks for the impossible (e.g. to `pop` an empty stack), throw an exception rather than trying to return some special value. The caller can handle the exception if they want - but they can avoid it by writing their code properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use null object pattern. Define a (shared) null `Song`.

```
class Song {
public:
    static const Song null_song;
};

Song Album::pop() {
    if (empty())
        return Song::null_song;
    return songs[top--];
}
```

Remember to initialize `Song::null_song`.

Comment: Thanks that was helpful, but one more thing is the initial value of top=-1 OK, or should I change it to something else, cause I think that can give me headaches.

Comment: I think it would be fine. You just need to handle the same stuff in different ways no matter you store top (beginning from -1) or size (beginning from 0).

Comment: Quick question how exactly should I initialize it , because I want it to have this view , or something similar:

Song::null_song
{
    title=new char [1];
    title[0]='\0';

    author=new char [1];
    author[0]='\0';

    year=0;

    length=0;
    original=NULL;
}

Comment: You should define `Song::Song()` correctly. Then, write `const Song Song::null_song(parameters);`

Comment: why not just nullptr? It implies C++11 but is  much cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Essentially, it seems as if what you are trying to do boils down to implementing a stack.

There is already a standard library class template for that, [std::stack](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/), that you can use.

Comment: `std::stack` isn't an STL container or STL anything for that matter.  But it is part of the standard.